# Google friend connect - simple question about API and .net variables

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-friend-connect

I want to store the **Person.Field.ID** number of a logged-in person in a .aspx .net variable so that I can use it in a VB script.  I am using the sign-in gadget on my site. How do I do this?

Comment: An ASPX.NET varible's value is a server side variable,

you can access it through vb script only by a POST/GET request
or you can use an AJAX appproach

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [.NET OpenSocial client library](http://code.google.com/p/opensocial-net-client/) and the [C# port](http://code.google.com/p/google-friend-connect-samples/source/browse/#svn/thechowdown-csharp/trunk) of the [Chow Down](http://chow-down.appspot.com/).  These would be two alternate methods for pulling in the GFC ID of the current viewer in .NET, though you'd probably have to translate the latter from C# to VB.NET if you wanted to use it, since it's not a shared library.  Unfortunately, I don't think the client library was written with Friend Connect in mind, so the simpler `fcauth` method probably isn't available.  You'll have to go through the [2-legged OAuth process](http://code.google.com/apis/friendconnect/serverside_integration.html#s2s-twolegged).  I assume the client library supports this, since it's a port of the Java version, which does.

If all that sounds too complicated, and all you really need is the ID, you might just pass it back with a simple Ajax/XHR call.  Here's the JS API call for getting the ID:

```
var req = opensocial.newDataRequest();
req.add(req.newFetchPersonRequest('VIEWER'), 'viewer');
req.send(function(response) {
  var data = response.get('viewer').getData();
  if (data) {
    visitorId = data.getId();
    // Send the ID to your server via Ajax/XHR here
  } else {
    // Not logged in
    visitorId = null;
  }
});
```

**Update:** You may also be interested in the project that Brian Clifton just released: [friendconnect-dotnet](http://code.google.com/p/friendconnect-dotnet/)